# Kali yuga according to the Mahabaratha

Tags: mahabharata, yuga, kali-yuga

> The inhabited regions of the earth will be afflicted with dearth and famine, and the highways will be filled with lustful men
>   and women of evil repute.

Hi, according to the Mahabharata during this era the world will be filled with lustful men, and evil women. Is this suggesting that all women are evil and that all men are lustful? Clearly this isn't the case, the world is also filled with a lot of good men and women?

Also is this passage describing the present, or the later part of kali yuga?

Comment: Please register. If you think the answer is what you are looking for and found helpful, then upvote and click the tick near the answer. It means the question is solved.

Answer (score 3):

#### The passage is speaking of the end of the Kali Yuga.

The conditions at the end of the Kali Yuga were narrated by Sage Markandeya to Yudhishtira. The passage doesn't suggest that men and women are lustful. It prophesies they *will be* lustful. So, it means that the end of the Yuga is not near. The sentence in the question is in the [chapter 189](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m03/m03189.htm) of Vana Parva. Sage Markandeya repeats the phrase "When the end of the Yuga will come" several times during the conversation. It is clear from the below excerpt from the chapter.

> O tiger among kings, **when the end of the Yuga will come**, the wife will never be content with her husband, nor the husband with his wife. And the possessions of men will never be much, and people will falsely bear the marks of religion, and jealousy and malice will fill the world. And no one will, at that time, be a giver (of wealth or anything else) in respect to any one else. **And the inhabited regions of the earth will be afflicted with dearth and famine, and the highways will be filled with lustful men and women of evil repute**.